# Change randomly half of the values of list

Tags: python, list, random

I'm working on 2D list on python and try to hide some values from the grid:

Imagine this is the grid:

```
[[0, 0, 1, 1], 
[0, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 0]]
```

the result I'm getting with this code:

```
    def startingArray(self,grid_copy): 
        for i in range (len(grid_copy)):
            n= self.CELL
            if n>len(grid_copy):
                grid_copy[i]=[2 for i in grid_copy]
            else:
                for i in range(n):
                    position=random.randrange(0,len(grid_copy[i]))
                    grid_copy[i][position]= 2  

[[2, 0, 1, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 1],
 [2, 0, 2, 2],
 [2, 1, 2, 2]]
```

it's fine but, I want something  where can hide exactly the half of the values randomly?
Any ideas?

Comment: What's the desired result?

Comment: Put all the coordinates in a list. Use `random.choices()` to select half of the coordinates randomly. Then hide those elements.

Comment: thank you @U12-Forward
i'm looking for somthing that can chang half element of grid in a random way
example :
before 
[[0, 0, 1, 1], 
[0, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 0]]

after 
[[0, 2, 1, 2], 
[2, 1, 0, 2],
[2, 2, 1, 0],
[1, 2, 2, 0]]

Comment: @Barmar `choices` uses sampling *with* replacement, so it's quite likely that one or more indices could be chosen multiple times.  Instead, leo should use `sample` to guarantee that 8 distinct coordinate pairs are chosen from the set of 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
def startingArray(self,grid_copy): 
    for row in grid_copy:
       prevItems = []
       for i in range(len(row)/2+1):
           if (i not in prevItems):
               row[random.randint(0, len(row) - 1)] = 2
               prevItems.append(i)
```

I didn't try this. But I think this will do what you expect.

Comment: This won't hide half the elements because you're counting the iterations where the `if` fails.